# How do I test TFT LCD?

Tags: lcd, tft

I decided to make my own display that I can connect it to Raspberry pi or Jetson nano. so I've recently bought TFT 480x480 LCD with ST7701S and RGB interface. I think I'm providing valid signal, but It doesn't seem to work, as It's always black no matter what I do. but I'm not sure if the LCD is broken or I'm doing something wrong.
Is there generic, low-cost and easy to use board that can be used to test it? I've heard there's "STM32F429I-DISC" for such use, but I want to know if there are other boards for it

Comment: A digital oscilloscope is a good investment...

Comment: I agree, but I'm a student and I don't think I can afford one. Is logic analyzer fine?

Comment: Wait it seems like logic analyzer is also expensive :(

Comment: @jsotola oh Sorry about that, I mean, I'm trying to make my own monitor that I can connect it to Raspberry pi or Jetson nano

Comment: For the data rates to your LCD a cheap Logic  Analyzer is all you need. There are models available for just $10-20 that are more than capable. Any of the ones based on the  CY7C68013A will operate with the open source Pulseview software. More professional units will cost $200 - 1000 depending on capability. No one should be without this a s a basic tool.

Comment: "I **think** I'm providing valid signal" can have so many things actually going wrong that I suspect buying an LCD specifically designed to work with RPi would be cheaper than buying all the tools you need to find out the problem.